# Youtube plugin for TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, youtube, tinymce

Does anybody know of a YouTube plugin for the latest version of TinyMCE?

I can't get the media plugin to work correctly for embedding YouTube videos as it is stripping out the embedded code even though I have all the extended_valid_elements option set.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can easily modify the Word Press plugin from : http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-youtube-embed/